# What is the purpose of keystores folder in react-native android project

Tags: keystore, android-keystore, react-native

I am currently struggling a bit with react native. I have successfully generated singed APK, followed steps mentioned in [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html). I have found that **react-native** android has different directory structure than the **android-studio**. There is folder with the name of **keystore** inside the react-native android project. What is purpose of that folder? Do I need to keep my keystore inside it? While [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html) say's place keystore file under the android/app directory.

Please share your thoughts. **Thanks**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you ever want to publish your app to the Play Store, you need to sign your app so that the Play Store can distinguish that it is actually you who is publishing to the store. The keystore file is as mentioned:

> A keystore is a binary file that contains one or more private keys. When you sign an APK for release using Android Studio, you can choose to generate a new keystore and private key or use a keystore and private key you already have. You should choose a strong password for your keystore, and a separate strong password for each private key stored in the keystore. You must keep your keystore in a safe and secure place. See Securing Your Private Key, below.

Related links:

- [App Signing - Developer Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)
- [Signed APK Android - React Native Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment, I know the value of the Keystore file but my question is about the keystore folder. What is that directory for? Please look at the screenshot and there is a folder named **keystores**

Comment: I believe React Native just stores your debug keystore files in that folder. Also if you look at how a keystore file is generated, it puts it there. Here are the [references in the Github repo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=keystores)